# Form validation in Play 2

Tags: java, validation, playframework, playframework-2.0

According to http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaForms page
"Since 2.0.2 the validate-method can return the following types: String, List or Map>"

But it doesn't appear to be so.

1)It works fine when String is returned

2 and 3) List and Map>  won't work

Log provided below

[2013-06-18 17:59:00.108] DEBUG play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 logging:make:28 - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerProvider

[2013-06-18 17:59:00.110]  INFO play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 Version::27 - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final

[2013-06-18 17:59:00.119] DEBUG play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 DefaultTraversableResolver:detectJPA:106 - Found javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath containing 'getPersistenceUtil'. Assuming JPA 2 environment. Trying to instantiate JPA aware TraversableResolver

[2013-06-18 17:59:00.120] DEBUG play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 DefaultTraversableResolver:detectJPA:117 - Instantiated JPA aware TraversableResolver of type org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.

[2013-06-18 17:59:00.122] DEBUG play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 
ValidationXmlParser:getValidationConfig:184 - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml for XML based Validator configuration.

[2013-06-18 17:59:00.126] DEBUG play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 ValidationXmlParser:getValidationConfig:187 - No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only.

[2013-06-18 17:59:00.302] DEBUG play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 PlatformResourceBundleLocator:getResourceBundle:72 - ValidationMessages not found.

[2013-06-18 17:59:00.304] DEBUG play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 PlatformResourceBundleLocator:getResourceBundle:69 - org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages found.

It should be admitted that according lo log format it wasn't created by play.Logger but another one.

Can anyone provide code snippet of validate() method returning List or Map> and some additional info about it.

```
    public Map<String, List<ValidationError>> validate() {
        Map<String,List<ValidationError>> errors = new HashMap<>();

        if (User.find.where().eq("login", login).findRowCount() > 0) {
            List<ValidationError> errorList = new ArrayList<>();
            errorList.add(new ValidationError("login", Messages.get("user.registration.notUniqueLogin", login), null));
            errors.put("login", errorList);
        }
        if (User.find.where().eq("email", email).findRowCount() > 0) {
            List<ValidationError> errorList = new ArrayList<>();
            errorList.add(new ValidationError("email", Messages.get("user.registration.notUniqueEmail", email), null));
            errors.put("email", errorList);
        }

        return errors;
    }
```

Comment: I recompiled the project. **Working!**. But strange logentries present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the validate method for a `Map`:

```
public Map<String, List<ValidationError>> validate()
{
  Map<String, List<ValidationError>> errors = new HashMap<String, List<ValidationError>>();
  // do validation
  return errors;
}
```

The map entry key is the name of your form field and the value is a `List` of all of the errors associated with that field. If you want to add a global error then I think you pass in an empty string `""` as the key.

`ValidationError` takes three parameters. The first is the key again, the second is the error message, and the third is the message arguments as a `List` of `Object`s.

Comment: I did just that. the error remains. in the log shows another reason